# my windows 7 machinework run properly on my sever 2008 domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking

Domain started out as a 32 but windows server 2003 then I upgrded to 32 bit windows server 2008 standard sp2 but my windows 7 machines just dont proform right. doing some reserch I am seeing that 64 bit windows server 2008 R2 is the perferred NOS for running windows7 host workstations.

Will windows 7 proform properly on a 32 bit server 2008 sp2? Or must it be R2?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for us to give a meaningful solution when the description of the problem is "just don't perform right".

I can tell you that I have Windows 7 clients working quite happily on a Windows 2003 domain with 32 bit Windows 2003 domain controllers. So as long as both client and server are supported there is no reason why you have to use a certain version of Window server to support certain versions of Windows clients.

Windows 2008 R2 might well provide the best server environment for easily taking advantage of Windows 7 client abilities because it is the version of windows server that is equivalent to Windows 7, but in terms of basic network behaviour and domain environment it isn't a *requirement*.